# Strategies for renaming table and indices while select queries are running

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a job which copies a large file to a table temp_a and also creates an index idx_temp_a_j on a column j. Now once the job finishes copying all the data, I have to rename this table to a table prod_a which is production facing and queries are always running against it with very less idle time. But once I run the rename queries, the queries coming in and the queries which are already running, are backed up producing high API error rates. I want to know what are the possible strategies I can implement so the renaming of the table happens with less downtime.

So far, below are the strategies I came up with:

1. First, just rename the table and allow queries to be backed up. This approach seems unreliable as rename table query acquires the EXCLUSIVE LOCK and all other queries are backed up, I am getting high level of API error rates.
2. Second, write a polling function which checks if there any queries running now if not then rename the table and index. In this approach the polling function will check periodically to see if any query is running, any queries are running, then wait , if not then run the alter table query. This approach will only queue up queries which are coming after the alter table rename query has placed an EXCLUSIVE LOCK on the table. Once the renaming finishes, the queued up queries will get executed. I still need to find database APIs which will help me in writing this function.

What are the other strategies which can allow this "seamless" renaming of the table? I am using postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.4 and the job which does all this is in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid blocking concurrent queries while a table is renamed.

The operation itself is blazingly fast, so any delay you experience must be because the `ALTER TABLE` itself is blocked by long running transactions using the table. All later operations on the table then have to queue behind the `ALTER TABLE`.

The solution for painless renaming is to keep database transactions very short (which is always desirable, since it also reduces the danger of deadlocks).